# How to get all parameters(Parameterized build) from jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, parameters

I am building one Parameterized pipeline job in newer version of jenkins.In older version of jenkins i have used getbinding().getVariables() to retrieve all parameters. But newer version it is return null values. How to retrieve parameters(all) in newer version of jenkins?

Comment: Since you mentioned versions--- Please add version details

Comment: Some choices mentioned in https://www.cyotek.com/blog/using-parameters-with-jenkins-pipeline-builds

Answer (score 14):

You can access parameters using "params" variable.

```
params.each {param ->
  println "${param.key} -> ${param.value} "
}
```

Comment: Hi Jayan. Thanks for the reply.But i need to trim the value of the parameters. I cant modify the parameters . It is showing unsupported exception. My need is trim the parameters.

Comment: @beersha : that is a different question

Comment: note that those lines should be inside a script {} section

Answer (score 5):

For string parameters, call `trim()`. Modifying @Jayan's example:

```
params.each {param ->
  println " '${param.key.trim()}' -> '${param.value.trim()}' "
}
```